# Drools 5 exposing it to web application and webservices(SOAP) using jaxb

Tags: drools

We have reqmt. where we need to expose drools 5 with ESB and similteniously with the web application.Although i have figured out ways to run drools with eclipse,however finding it difficult to configure Drools 5 with same web-app at the moment and shift it esb in future.
Guvnor and Drool-Server are not just sufficient to help me out neither does googling it helps
,even spring support is also not available.

Any help will be highly appreciated...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At what level do you need to "expose" Drools within the ESB?  I use Drools in an Enterprise solution that uses asynchronous web services; many of my workflows are extremely long running (2 weeks to a month).  The key is to temporarily persist the StatefulKnowledgeSession between calls.  There is a JPAStatefulKnowledgeSession that serializes the session and stores it as a blob in a relational database.  I decided not to use this solution because many of my asynchronous tasks finish within a second of being called.  The performance cost of persisting the process in a RDBMS was too much for my needs.  My solution was to store the session in an in-memory cache.  Infinispan was ridiculously simple to configure and use, and I haven't had a single issue with the framework.

Do you need to have the ESB and Web Application use the same KnowledgeSession?  Does it have to be a StatefulKnowledgeSession?  If you need to maintain state, you should consider a queue-based system and fireAllRules() at some interval.  If your actions are command based (insert object, start process, etc), I believe Drools already has an API for the pattern (I believe this is what Drools Server does under the hood).  You could also make the KnowledgeSession a singleton; but consider using a ReentrantLock to prevent concurrent calls on the object.  If you are isolating sessions, creating your own repository works best.  Infinispan's Cache implements the ConcurrentHashMap, so you could use the ID of the session as the key and KnowledgeSession as the value.